# Is this a Separation of Concerns?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm creating a program that analyzes comments in Word documents (in terms of their textual content). However, occasionally one who wants to analyze the textual data may like to change some of the comments content. Yet I think it's better to leave word processing functionalities to the word processing program itself and tell the user to do this in Word. In other words, I don't want to get into the mess of saving Word documents and the user may also be more comfortable editing the document in Word environment.

Can I call this a Separation of Concerns (SoC)? I guess the situation may not be called SoC because it is related to functions in separate programs (mine and Word).

**Note:** This is my own project I do not want to convince an employer to demand less features. I just think that there is really no need to chase with editing Word documents and I should focus on the specialized functionality of my program itself. I want to keep it simple, in other words. However, I need a scientific explanation for this as I want to publish the tool in a journal. I want to present a firm rationale for what I'm doing. Anyway, if I'm not doing it right, I need firm reasons for that too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns.  There's really no such thing as a "Separation of Concerns Design;" rather, SoC is one of several principles that are applied to the design process to enable better software designs to be created.

Comment: You can use example of Git which use external editor to edit commit messages

Comment: I think you're confusing "separation of concern" with "I'm not getting paid enough for this".  I can see how you'd confuse the two, they sound very similar.  Joking aside, I would tend to agree with you.  If you end up doing this anyway, word to the wise:  write *well-defined* rules that the client understands fully to determine which comments are edited.

Answer (score 3):

The story I think I'm hearing is you are currently committed to creating a program that analyzes comments in word documents. Someone is proposing a new feature that would let people change comments. You want to push back but want to know the professional way to do that. You're reaching for some design principle buzzwords but aren't sure.

What you're up against here is called [feature creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep). You thought the project was just going to be x and now people are also talking about y.

The professional attitude is that y is fine but don't tell me it's still just x. Y needs its own justification, it's own time to complete, you don't get y for free when you ask for x.

What you can do is leverage what you've learned that relates to both x and y. There might even be code that can be reused. But no matter how related they are don't let them convince you that tacking y onto x isn't real work, because it is.

Answer (score 2):

SoC is the process of dissecting a piece of software into distinct features that encapsulate unique behavior and data that can be used by other classes. Generally, a concern represents a feature or behavior of a class. The act of separating a program into discrete responsibilities significantly increases code reuse, maintenance, and testability.

Having said that, I believe SoC is **not** a suitable explanation -especially, a scientific one, to back your desire to keep your application with R funtionality only instead of CRUD.

Personally, I wouldn't use the term "SoC" in *this context*. Your question is about the **breadth** of your application; how far you want it to go in terms of features and functionality; the purpose of your application itself. It is a matter of **User Requirements Specification** and not a matter of SoC.

Think it the other way around. Suppose you finally decide to allow for updates of comments (maybe because the analysis suggests such updates and you want to provide the means to apply them to the document from your software). Now, this is a distinct feature and you should certainly apply SoC to encapsulate it in your application; SoC can certainly be used in *this context* to reason yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns in a software engineering context means something different. When we (programmers) talk about concerns or responsibilities, we think pieces of code in a program. What people are supposed to do what and what not is hardly ever any of our concern(!). A system administrator may think this way when assigning access rights. We do not recognize people, we prefer to focus on code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, making your program only responsible for analysing the comments, and letting an existing software component (in this case the Word processor) be the only responsible part of the system for changing the documents can IMHO be called Separation of Concerns. SoC is not tied to functions, it is a term which can be applied to all kind of software components of different size and on different levels of abstraction.

However, just because this term can be applied, don't draw any premature conclusions that this separation is a good way of designing the system from the end users point of view, or for declining the feature. For a user, I can imagine it making sense to have a comment changing feature integrated to your analysing feature, for example, by position to specific comments which were picked by the analysis.

You could still implement this by adding another component which allows to control the editing, apart from the analysing component. That would still be a design which separates the concerns.

Of course, when the "comment editing" request does not bring any benefit for the user when compared to direct editing using the Word processor, then this is an economical reason not to implement this feature (and not a "buzzword reason").